# dynamoDB , define index

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, database, nosql

Suppose I have below item as an example in dynamo db.

I want to create an index, `person_id` is primary key.

I want to use `"next_haircut->month"` as sort key.

My question is, in ec2 console, what string should I use for sort ke
is it `"next_haircut.month"` , or  just `"month"` or something else.

Thanks

```
{
  "person_id" : 123,
  "last_name" : "Barr",
  "first_name" : "Jeff",
  "current_city" : "Tokyo",
  "next_haircut" :
  {
    "year" : 2014,
    "month" : 10,
    "day" : 30
  },
  "children"  :
    [ "SJB", "ASB", "CGB", "BGB", "GTB" ]
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found the answer.
The answer is : No. I can not do that.

Link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html

The key schema for the index. Every attribute in the index key schema must be a ***top-level attribute*** of type String, Number, or Binary. Other data types, including documents and sets, are not allowed. Other requirements for the key schema depend on the type of index: